# SET XACT_ABORT OFF if transaction terminated by SET XACT_ABORT ON

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, transactions

I read that many tend to `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning of the procedure.

```
CREATE PROC myProc
AS
Begin
BEGIN TRAN
 SET XACT_ABORT ON
 [..code1 that might throw an error..]
 [..code2..]
 SET XACT_ABORT OFF [?]
COMMIT TRAN
END
SET XACT_ABORT OFF [?]
```

Because run-time errors will terminate the procedure, `SET XACT_ABORT` will be left as `ON`. I have some questions :

1. Where do you set it on ? Before the `CREATE PROC` definition, after `BEGIN` or after `BEGIN TRAN` ? `SET` is at connection level so I suppose all three would not make a difference ?
2. When do you turn it `OFF` if it is left `ON` when errors occur ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting XACT_ABORT before the CREATE PROC definition doesn't have much sense. Unlike ANSI_NULLS or QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, this option is not stored as a property of the stored procedure. I would say that you should set XACT_ABORT immediately after `CREATE PROC myProc AS` or after the first `BEGIN`, where you would also place the SET NOCOUNT ON.

I would not bother setting XACT_ABORT off. If any code portion needs to have it off (for example, inside a TRY-CATCH block that ignores some errors), it should set it off inside that specific TRY block, and set it back on at the end of END CATCH.

For more info, see: http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why would we want it ON when the default is OFF ?

Comment: See http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification for details.